# Print Variables Within Laravel HTML Helper Input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel form created with a Laravel Form Helper. I want each of these fields to be unique so I declared a counter variable like so:

```
{{counter=0}}
```

I increment this variable inside my foreach loop, so I can use it on the ID element of each input, like so:

```
{{Form::text('company_lookup', null, ['class'=>'form-control typeahead', 'id'=>'company_lookup_{{$counter}}', 'placeholder' => 'Type company registration number or name'])}}
```

What is the right syntax to do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
@if(count(Auth::user()->institution_user))
{{$counter=0}}
@foreach(Auth::user()->institution_user as $company)
{{$counter++}}
<input type='hidden' value="{{$counter}}" name="lookup"/>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('company_lookup', 'Institution lookup', array('class' => 'control-label'))}}
        {{Form::text('company_lookup', null, ['class'=>'form-control typeahead', 'id'=>'company_lookup_{{$counter}}',
        'placeholder' => 'Type company registration number or name', 'lookup'=>'$counter'])}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 mr-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('company_registration_number', 'Registration Number', array('class' => 'control-label'))}}
        {{Form::text('company_registration_number[]', $company->company_registration_number, ['class'=>'form-control',
        'id'=>'company_registration_number_$counter'])}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('company_name', 'Institution Name', array('class' => 'control-label'))}}
        {{Form::text('company_name[]', $company->company_name, ['class'=>'form-control',
        'id'=>'company_name_$counter'])}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('company_address', 'Business Address', array('class' => 'control-label'))}}
        {{Form::textarea('company_address[]', $company->company_address, array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3',
        'id'=> 'company_address_$counter'))}}

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-11">
    <hr>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You also need to make their name unique. 'name' => company_lookup_{{$counter}}

Comment: Please show how you are iterating `Form::text`.

Comment: I have updated the original post to show how I am iterating all over the form. I tried {{$counter}} but I got an error.

Comment: They are arrayed, the names don't have to be unique..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain an enumerated counter like this:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->institution_user as $index => $company)
```

`$index` is internally available in blade and will be incremented in each iteration.

Also, if you want to use `$counter` as in your example, all you have to do is use `<?php ?>` instead of `{{ }}`.

Comment: How do I use index like in my example. What is the right syntax to use with a form builder?

Comment: Just use `$index` instead of `$counter`.

Comment: I don't know if I am making myself clear. Have used that before? because this is giving me an error
`{{Form::text('company_lookup', null, ['class'=>'form-control typeahead', 'id'=>'company_lookup_{{$index}}', 'placeholder' => 'Type company registration number or name', 'lookup'=>''])}} `

`syntax error, unexpected '}'`

Comment: It should be `'company_lookup_'. $index,'`, you can't use `{{ }}` within `{{ }}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the syntax I have been asking about... I get that error a lot and most times I just end up reverting to normal HTML..

Comment: Ok, keep in mind that what's between `{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` is plain php.